# PostgreSQL unique constraint error when setting up foreign key relation in Exposed (Kotlin)

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, orm, ktor, kotlin-exposed

"I am trying to setup a one-to-one relation between two tables (Users and RefreshTokens) using JetBrains' Exposed ORM library in Kotlin.

I have defined the tables as follows:

```
object Users : IdTable<UUID>() {
    override val id = uuid("user_id").entityId()
    val name = varchar("name", 255)
    val email = varchar("email", 255).uniqueIndex()
    val passwordHash = varchar("password_hash", 60)
}

object RefreshTokens: IdTable<UUID>() {
    override val id = uuid("refresh_token_id").entityId()
    val userId = reference("user_id", Users).uniqueIndex()
    val token = varchar("token", 255)
    val expiresAt = datetime("expires_at")
}
```

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database and attempting to create the schema with the following function:

```
fun Application.configureDatabase() {
    Database.connect(
        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ktordb",
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
        user = "root",
        password = "1234"
    )

    transaction {
        SchemaUtils.create(Users)
        SchemaUtils.create(RefreshTokens)
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get an error indicating there is no unique constraint matching the keys for the referenced table "users".

The error message:

`ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"`

I have tried making the 'id' column in the Users table a primary key and unique, but the error persists. Could anyone provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
object Users : UUIDTable(name = "user_test", columnName = "user_id") {
    val name = varchar("name", 255)
    val email = varchar("email", 255).uniqueIndex()
    val passwordHash = varchar("password_hash", 60)
}

object RefreshTokens: UUIDTable(name = "token_test", columnName = "refresh_token_id") {
    val userId = reference("user_id", Users).uniqueIndex()
    val token = varchar("token", 255)
    val expiresAt = datetime("expires_at")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding this line to User object:

```
override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(id, name = "PK_USER_ID")
```